# Fetching different language's HTML data from multilingual website

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, multilingual, fetch

There is a **multilingual** website. When I view the html source from browser, I see the data in my language. But when I create a webrequest and fetch HTML, I get the data in English.

- In my browser, lang attribute is: lang="tr" xml:lang="tr"
- When I fetch the HTML it is: lang="en" xml:lang="en"

I want to fetch the HTML in Turkish. How can I do this?

---

This is how I fetch:

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(webUrl);
        request.Method = "POST";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("");
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        htmlcontent = reader.ReadToEnd();

        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add [`Accept-Language`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) request header. In .NET you could use [`HttpRequestHeader.ContentLanguage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfb6df42%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like this:

```
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = 
                                         "tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4";
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I used the same in other way as:
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: tr-tr,tr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");

Answer (score 2):

```
WebHeaderCollection headerCollection = request.Headers;    
headerCollection.Add("Accept-Language:tr");
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I used sth similar as:
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: tr-tr,tr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");

Answer (score 0):

In your WebRequest, add a header entry for:

```
 Accept-Language: tk
```

Which will tell ASP.NET your preferred language. You have to have implemented language switching functionality. MSDN has a page for [ASP.NET Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) here.